# How to call a bool type function with several arguments objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        // app already launched
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        // This is the first launch ever
        return  YES;
    }
}
```

How would I call this function in another method of the same class it is in.

Comment: I can't understand why you want to call a delegate method? For the sake of your understanding, delegates can never be explicitly called. And why you returning NO? Read apple developer docs to see what this method is for.

Comment: What do u wanna exactly ?

Answer (score 3):

This is a delegate method, and **you never call it explicitly**.

It is called as soon as the application finished launching.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSUserDefaults *preferences = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// to access the value of HasLaunchedOnce, write:
[preferences valueForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]; 

// to set the value of HasLaunchedOnce, write:
[preferences setValue:TRUE forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
```

You can use this anywhere in the app.